# Which ones are accurate? "Print / Printed Book", "Print / Printed Paper", "Print / Printed Newspaper"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, It seems that "*Printed Book*" is more popular than "*Print Book*" but "*Print paper*" is more popular than "*Printed Paper*" (Printed Paper could mean paper that is printed with pictures on it, see http://www.papermojo.com/Printed-Paper_c_1.html) but "*Printed Newspaper*" is more popular than "*Print Newspaper*".

See the Ngram analysis:

[Ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Print%20book%2C%20Printed%20Book&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPrint%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPrinted%20Book%3B%2Cc0)

[Ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Print%20Paper%2C%20Printed%20Paper&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPrint%20Paper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPrinted%20Paper%3B%2Cc0)

[Ngram 3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Print%20newspaper%2C%20Printed%20Newspaper&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPrinted%20Newspaper%3B%2Cc0)

So, Which ones are accurate? "*Print / Printed Book*", "*Print / Printed Paper*", "*Print / Printed Newspaper*"

Comment: Can you please cite sources that show what you're saying is true? Where do you get the information that one version is more popular than the other?

Comment: Remember that Ngrams doesn't ever tell you the full story. "large print book" is an example that would turn up regularly but would not apply to this example. Similarly, "out of print book".

Comment: or you can do the search from internet and compare them

Comment: I think, in general it is called print media. So.. I'd prefer using "print". Though if there's an electronic copy, I'd have it printed first.

Comment: Every combination of [print, printed] and [book, paper, newspaper] is appropriate in at least some situations. Without knowing what idea you're trying to convey, no one can tell you which is the correct structure.

Answer (score 1):

At least in India, we refer 'print paper' to a paper used in any electronic printer. So, I may ask...

> Get me a print paper. I want to take a print-out of this soft copy.

On the other hand, printed paper means a paper with something printed on it.

> Ah, not this me. Give me a blank paper. This one is printed and thus of no use.

Or what you showed in your example.

About print book/newspaper, I'm not sure. Never heard of that. Furthermore, 'printed' newspaper/book also seems redundant. Because if it's empty/blank, it cannot be newspaper or a book (-unless you are talking about a blank notebook or you are a newspaper and importing blank 'newsprint paper' in bulk).

To clarify:

Print/Printer paper -

[image: Print or printer paper]

Printed paper -

[image: Printed paper]

Newsprint paper -

[image: newsprint paper]

Printed newspaper -

[image: Printed newspaper]

Comment: That's interesting.  In the US, I believe it's more common to say "printer/binder/notebook paper" to describe the paper loaded into the respective objects.

Comment: I think that in Britain we would call the first example "printing paper" or possibly *printer paper".  The second would be "printed wallpeper", And the third would be "newsprint" (without any mention of paper).

Answer (score 0):

If we [search Google books for "print paper"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22print%20paper%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1909,cd_max:1943&lr=lang_en) in the years 1909-1943, when the (unsmoothed) [Ngram analysis](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Print%20Paper%2CPrinted%20Paper&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=0) records it as more popular than "printed paper," most of the results refer to "news-print paper." In contemporary English there is no longer a hyphen in the word "newsprint."